# Publish VS Code Extension with limited visibility

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to provide access to VS Code extension (preview mode) to limited (and perhaps selective) audience before publishing it to public access?

Answer (score 2):

You can sideload an extension either with a vsix or just sending your project folder and having them paste the folder in the VSCode extension folder. You can leave your src folder in or out of the folder you're sending.

In your project's package.json make sure to add a publisher and description or it wont show up in the extensions list.

https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/install-extension/